# VB.NET best data type for storing currency values

Tags: vb.net, types, currency

What is the most appropriate data type for storing currency values in VB.NET?

Comment: It should be noted that this is probably true for most .net languages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Decimal` (alias for [`System.Decimal` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) in the BCL) is designed for storing monetary values. It's a 128 bit decimal floating point type (as opposed to binary floating point) and is useful for storing "real-world" values with high decimal precision. By real-world, I specifically mean measurements that are originally made in decimal. Double is generally suitable for calculations that don't need as much accuracy when they are represented as decimal numbers.

> The Decimal value type represents decimal numbers ranging from positive 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 to negative 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335. The Decimal value type is appropriate for **financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors**. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding. For example, the following code produces a result of 0.9999999999999999999999999999 rather than 1.

Comment: That's what I thought. Why do I often see Double used?

Comment: Because some accountants don't lose sleep over a billionth of a penny.

Comment: It is not "a billionth of a penny". Binary floating point cannot store 0.02

Comment: @LucioM.Tato Or even 0.1. http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/