# Incorrect value for double calculation in vb6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, double

When adding 2 values in vb6 i get some odd behavior.

When variable sum (type double) is printed for different cases in immediate window as below.

I got results as :

```
sum =0                      sum =0                      sum =0 
sum =74.46+0.41             sum = 74.87                 sum=97.8+0.41
?sum                        ?sum =74.87                 ?sum
74.87                       TRUE                        98.21
?sum =74.87                                             sum=98.21
FALSE                                                   TRUE
```

When checked the same in vb.net we get the result as below:

```
sum =0                      sum =0                      sum =0  
?sum                        sum = 74.87                 sum=97.8+0.41   
0                           ?sum =74.87                 ?sum    
sum =74.46+0.41             TRUE                        98.21   
?sum                                                    ?sum=98.21  
74.8699999999999                                        TRUE
```

From the above result  we can say the result "**False**" since in vb6 the value is equal to 74.8699999999999.

1. Then why in vb6 result shown as 74.87?
2. In vb.net case expected value
   =74.87 but actual value =74.8699999999999 **why the error occurs** only for certain values ?
3. This kind of behavior occurs for which
   values?

Comment: Floating point variables (single and double data types in vb6), are only approximate values, due to how they are represented internally. There are no errors here, this can be the expected behavior for floating point operations. And the same can occur with vb.net (and c++, c#, etc), though your particular test values here apparently aren't doing so, could be a rounding behavior between the runtimes.

Comment: The underlying issue which MarkL alludes to is that floating point is in **binary** fractions, so only decimal fractions that correspond to fractional powers of two (like 0.5, 0.25) can be represented exactly.  Neither 7.446e1 nor 4.1e-1 has a fractional part that is a fractional power of two, so both are approximated, and when you add them up, the least significant bit may end up being different (due to the chosen approximation for each addend) than what you get when you specify 74.87 directly.

Comment: When you convert floating point values to strings, the runtimes try to be helpful and show you what they think the number is meant to be, not what it is exactly (you don't want a number assigned as 0.41 printed as 0.410000000000003 for example, error chosen arbitrarily here and isn't necessarily the error you would see in practice).  That's why you can get two numbers that aren't identically equal still printed out as "74.87".

Comment: Canonical refs on this include "What every computer scientist should know about floating point" and Bruce Dawson's posts on floating point grouped here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

Comment: If you are only interested in two decimal points, consider using the `Currency` type in VB6.  For VB.NET, consideration of this article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256064/vb-net-best-data-type-for-storing-currency-values) seems to indicate the recommendation to use `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Currency type in VB6 allows four decimal digits, better than two but not nearly as many as .net decimal and much slower than floating point numbers.At least is predictable: four digits are sometimes not enough even for storing values related to money, some unit prices I have to deal in Euro fractions of cents require more digits.

sum =0@
sum =74.46@+0.41@
?sum
74.87
?sum =74.87@
True