# Numerical Bug in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Go to the immediate window in Visual Basic 6 and type

```
?(2.42+0.58)=3.00
```

This statement returns `True` as you'd expect

But this returns `False`!

```
?(2.42+0.57)=2.99
```

Note, it seems to be related to Double numerical types, if converted to another type its ok, eg

```
?CCur(2.42+0.57)=2.99
```

Why ??!  Is this a bug in the VB compiler?

Comment: Here's a recent question that provides [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70617554/5162073).

Comment: It seems that this lesson has to be learned, or re-learned, person by person for all time.

Comment: Is there a canonical answer for this in VB6? Or even just more generally?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5162073) that's a little more in depth on the topic.

Comment: @BrianMStafford thanks! Very similar to this Q and language-agnostic, seems like a good fit to me.

Comment: @userSteve This works `? CDec(2.42) + 0.58 = 3.00`

Comment: @wqw Yes, that works, but +0.57 does not

Comment: @userSteve This works too `? CDec(2.42) + 0.57 = 2.99`